# Treeview items don't expand

Tags: wpf, vb.net, treeview, treeviewitem

I'm developing a WPF application for my company, and everything needs to look the same way corresponding to our company's look. Therefore I have to make a custom folder explorer, which will feature a treeview of the current directory.

In order to make it easier, I've made the following class, which is basically a `TreeViewItem` that stores a `DirectoryInfo` and automaticely browses subfolders when expanded (not to browse everything at once and make the software faster). Here is my code :

```
Private Class TreeViewPlus
    Inherits TreeViewItem
    Public dir As IO.DirectoryInfo

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(dir As DirectoryInfo)
        Me.dir = dir
        Try
            If Not dir.EnumerateDirectories Is Nothing Then   'If there are subdirectories, I add an empty item to enable the expansion
                Me.Items.Add(New TreeViewPlus)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub TreeViewPlus_Expanded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Expanded

        Me.Items.Clear()

        Try
            For Each folder In dir.EnumerateDirectories()
                Dim item As TreeViewPlus = New TreeViewPlus(folder)
                item.Name = Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(folder.FullName, "[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "")
                item.Header = folder.Name
                Me.Items.Add(item)
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

And here is the code where I initialize the first directories: (TRV_Arbre is the name of my TreeView)

```
Sub New()
...
    For Each Drive As IO.DriveInfo In IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives
        Dim item As TreeViewPlus = New TreeViewPlus(Drive.RootDirectory)
        item.Header = Drive.Name
        TRV_Arbre.Items.Add(item)
    Next
...
End Sub
```

The Issue I've got is that the first level of items correctly expand, but not the following ones.

See here : https://youtu.be/E6BJbKal5Sk

I've already debugged my code a little, and it correctly creates the different  Items.

Can anyone help me for this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple way to solve this problem and that is to Override the OnExpanded Sub on the Base TreeViewItem class instead of implementing your own Expanded method. Then in the end you execute MyBase.OnExpanded(e) method which seems to contain the correct update events to send out to whomever listens. In this case your TreeView.

```
 Protected Overrides Sub OnExpanded(e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Me.Items.Clear()

    Try
        For Each folder In dir.EnumerateDirectories()
            Dim item As TreeViewPlus = New TreeViewPlus(folder)
            item.Name = Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(folder.FullName, "[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "")
            item.Header = folder.Name
            Me.Items.Add(item)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    MyBase.OnExpanded(e)
End Sub
```